# Firebase real time database rule for preventing user from set

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Firebase Real Time Database when using with Javascript user can inspect element with chrome and change the push function to set.

In this case all the data will remove and only new data added without Firebase id. I use some rules like `newData.exists()` and `!Data.exists()` and etc.

How can I prevent this case?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that you want to fail, and the minimal, complete rules that show what you've tried already. Without such a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard to say more something concrete.

Comment: in google code lab example (https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat-web) if you deploy it and change the push to set in saveMessage function it will delete all the data